# How can I make a (functional) checksum for an open source project?

Tags: checksum, godot

A friend of mine is working on a project in Godot, a simple multiplayer game where players connect to each other over IPs. Recently he decided to make his git repo for it public, instead of keeping it private; essentially making it accessible to the world.

However he soon realized that by making the project files public, people would now be able to compile a slightly modified version of the code and still connect to other players. Seeing how this could be exploited for cheating (ex. opponent's turn never comes) he asked me for help. As I'm also a frequent grand strategy player the first thing to come to my mind was making something like a checksum for comparing between different versions. Alas, most of these games are closed-source, I realized this when he asked what would happen if someone was able to "hard-code" or force a check-sum to match.

Would using a closed-source component for either a launcher or in-game online authentication be a good idea? Or are there any other approaches he could consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You won't be prevent cheating.

For an online game to work, the server *has* to send information to clients, and that information can be abused. If the server sends player locations to the clients, a malicious client could intercept these messages and use it to build a map of all their opponents, or show their locations through walls.

Similarly, the server *must* accept commands from clients and use them to modify the game state. Determining whether commands are legitimate or not is exceptionally difficult. How do you tell the difference between a highly skilled player and an aimbot? Some AAA games use anti-cheat solutions that try, yet still let cheaters through while banning regular humans.

## This isn't about open source

The good news is that this has little to do free software. As much as you try to lock down the code, players *will* crack it and find ways to cheat. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4637/140575) is about DRM, but gives a good overview about why it is essentially impossible to prevent smart, determined people from reverse-engineering technology.

## Use an authoritative server

While cheating cannot be prevented, you can limit its effectiveness. You can't control the clients, but you *can* control the server, so make it [authoritative](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-server-game-architecture.html). Every decision relevant to the outcome of the game should be made by the server, while the clients are responsible for little more than forwarding player inputs to the server. This means that if a player wants to "hack" their local copy by, say, giving their player 500% health, this will only screw things up on their side -- the server will still act as though their player has a normal amount of health.

## Limit the information you send

While your authoritative server prevents players from modifying game state, they can still abuse information sent to their client. As mentioned above, the server will *have* to send information about player locations to clients, and players could use this to discover opponent locations or create aimbots. You can limit this by sending the absolute minimum amount of information necessary for a client to work properly. For example, instead of constantly sending player location updates, the server might only send updates on players that the client can see. This would prevent players from having "x-ray" vision, but still wouldn't protect against aimbots (remember than even proprietary games don't manage to prevent this).

## Consider your threat model

Players can only use server information to cheat if knowlege of this information isn't "part of the game". For example, if you are making a chess game, players can't "cheat" by intercepting messages from the server, because those messages don't contain any information they shouldn't know -- they're already "allowed" to know the location of their opponents pieces by the rules.

When you look at your game, try to figure out what absolutely *needs* to be secret for the desired mechanics to work, and make the rest public knowledge. For the bits that do need to be secret, limit sending them as much as possible.

With that in mind, congratulate your friend for creating an open source game. If anything, this means you'll be able to get more help making it as cheat-proof as possible. Good luck!